# Error building Memory Heap Snapshot (Electron 1.7.9 w/ Chrome Devtools) - Bug, or user error?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, electron, devtools

When I build the heap snapshot it gets to the step `Building postorder index...`

At this point it fails with the following messages:

`An error occurred when a call to method 'buildSnapshot' was requested
TypeError: Cannot read property '1388388' of undefined
    at HeapSnapshotWorker.JSHeapSnapshotNode.name (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/heap_snapshot_worker.js?remoteBase=https…olor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)&experiments=true:1155:122)
    at HeapSnapshotWorker.JSHeapSnapshot._buildPostOrderIndex (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/heap_snapshot_worker.js?remoteBase=https…Color=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)&experiments=true:979:119)
    at HeapSnapshotWorker.JSHeapSnapshot.initialize (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/heap_snapshot_worker.js?remoteBase=https…olor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)&experiments=true:899:2591)
    at new HeapSnapshotWorker.JSHeapSnapshot (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/heap_snapshot_worker.js?remoteBase=https…olor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)&experiments=true:1095:387)
    at HeapSnapshotWorker.HeapSnapshotLoader.buildSnapshot (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/heap_snapshot_worker.js?remoteBase=https…Color=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)&experiments=true:1205:85)
    at HeapSnapshotWorker.HeapSnapshotWorkerDispatcher.dispatchMessage (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/heap_snapshot_worker.js?remoteBase=https…olor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)&experiments=true:1255:509)`

Is it possible I have done something in my code to cause this? Asking here to avoid accidentally filing a frivolous bug report. Thanks very much!

Comment: Regardless of what you did or did not, Electron should handle it gracefully instead of choking so I'd report it (with a simplified test case to reproduce the error easily).